# Support TLSv1.0 or SSLv3 on Android in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to fetch a site which is using TLSv1 protocol, but when I use fetch to request, react native will throw a error: `Network request failed`.
I just normally fetch like this:

```
fetch('https://stu255.ntust.edu.tw/ntust_stu/stu.aspx')
  .then((r) => { return r.text(); })
  .catch((e) => { console.error(e); })
  .then((r) => { console.warn(r); });
```

And the certification of that site is:

```
---
SSL handshake has read 3076 bytes and written 632 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: D118    0000199B804B84C7EC06FF6CAFEBEB96617DA1721EFA42FD2CD1B350350C
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: A93C9E54CEAB4235C64EB3A0799CA3761F13EACEA0B0FE34D377DBD615A666CE13EB7E58DF18E96E30AA1C97644CF050
    Start Time: 1530941378
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Finally, I found that react native use okhttp to implement network in Android, but doesn't support TLSv1.0 by default.

I wonder how to enable TLSv1.0 on Android?

Thanks.

Comment: `return r.text;` Are you sure you don't mean `return r.text();` ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh sorry,I typed wrongly. But it isn't directly related to this problem

Comment: @splitline Any updates on this?